# Different IP series for Wireless Clients

Tags: networking, dhcp-server

We have following simple setup ...

- Active Directory (2008) Server, IP address  10.0.0.1/8 with DHCP    server configured.
- Users gets ip from this DHCP , pool  **10.0.0.2-10.0.0.255 (/8)**
- Data Center have **Cisco 3750** switch, and all users connected with different 10 **Cisco Catalyst 500/SRW2024** switches in different dept. All switches are connected with the data center 3750 switch via normal UPLinks (sfp).
- We have around **10 Ubiquiti AP-LR Access Points** connected with different switches.
- Currently there is **NO VLAN** config on any switch, all running on default.

How can I assign different IP pool to Wireless clients

**Example:**

- Wireless clients should get IP from range **10.10.10.1- 10.10.10.255 (/8)**  so that I can distinguish them easily. **I don't want to ISOLATE any user**, they should be on same subnet, security is not concerned here. no restriction is required on user to user/server communication.

Just wifi client should get ip from second pool from windows DHCP

Comment: You can do inter VLAN routing in your L3 switch.